# How can we generate a single dictionary for the output of the code below?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Consider the following code, which is a simple code:

```
import networkx as nx
import math

G = nx.read_gml(".../networks/karate.gml",label=None)

X = nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,5,2)
t = 0 
for x in X:
    if (34,x) in G.edges() or (x,34) in G.edges():
        t += 1
    l = dict()
    l[x] = t + math.log10(5)
    print(l)
```

An example of the output of this code is as follows:

```
{5: 1.6989700043360187}
{1: 1.6989700043360187}
{11: 2.6989700043360187}
{7: 3.6989700043360187}
{32: 4.698970004336019}
{2: 5.698970004336019}
{3: 6.698970004336019}
{4: 7.698970004336019}
{6: 8.698970004336019}
```

How can we put these outputs into a dictionary or two? It means to merge them together.

We expect an output like the following:

```
{5: 1.6989700043360187, 1: 1.6989700043360187, 11: 2.6989700043360187, 7: 3.6989700043360187, 32: 4.698970004336019, 2: 5.698970004336019, 3: 6.698970004336019, 4: 7.698970004336019 ,6: 8.698970004336019}
```

Comment: Initialize `l` outside of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `l = dict()` outside and above the `for`, and unindent the `print(l)` line. Like this:

```py
import networkx as nx
import math

G = nx.read_gml(".../networks/karate.gml",label=None)

X = nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,5,2)
t = 0 
l = dict()
for x in X:
    if (34,x) in G.edges() or (x,34) in G.edges():
        t += 1
    l[x] = t + math.log10(5)
print(l)
```

Explanation: the code inside the loop (i.e. below the `for` line, indented) runs many times, once for each iteration of the loop. Since you want to create a single `dict`, and you want to print it once (after the loop has finished), you have to move those lines outside the loop.

Please note that the shorter and more common form `l = {}` does the same as `l = dict()`.

Comment: I was involved in this issue for several days. Thank you very much. Good luck.